# Regenerate OpenSSH Host Keys

Tags: ssh

How should I regenerate ssh keys for OSX? The system is running El Capitan if that is relevant information.

(To clarify, I am not asking for `ssh-keygen  remote-server` as a USER but to change the keys inside the serverside-sshd). In Ubuntu-Linux you delete  `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` and `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`.

Answer (score 3):

In Mac, you should be able to delete the `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` too and run `ssh-keygen -A`, which will generate the missing keys.

Comment: -A      For each of the key types (rsa1, rsa,
             dsa, ecdsa and ed25519) for which host
             keys do not exist, generate the host keys
             with the default key file path, an empty
             passphrase, default bits for the key
             type, and default comment.  This is used
             by /etc/rc to generate new host keys.